# Python Invalid property name Python Kivy Md

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Im a begginer in Python so  I dont understand well how the language works. i tried to launch this code which puts an image on the program.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<KivyButton>:

    Button: 
        text: 'viva la vida'
  
        size_hint: .20, .10

        Image: 
            
        source: 'Arnorld.jpg'
        center_x: self.parent.center_x: 
        center_y: self.parent.center_x: 
        

""")


class KivyButton(App, BoxLayout):

    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__=="__main__":
    KivyButton().run()
```

ERROR:

```
kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 3:
 ...
       1:
       2:
 >>    3:     <KivyButton>:
       4:
       5:
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

Comment: I assume it doesn't like the `<>` characters.

Comment: Thanks man I just Changed the name of the <> from KivyButton to BotonKivy and it solved magiclly